# Alamore fire Post Request Converting to Get request in server logs

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, post, alamofire

I am trying to make post request in swift with alamofire library. What i am doing is :-

```
let request = Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: APIParameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.prettyPrinted, headers: HeaderParameters)

        request.validate().responseJSON { (response) in
            switch response.result {
            case .success:
                print(response)

                break
            case .failure(let error):

                print(error)
            }

            completionHandler(true,nil,response.result.value)
        }
```

API Parameter is

```
▿ 2 elements

      ▿ 0 : 2 elements
        - key : "mobileNumber"
        - value : "**********"
      ▿ 1 : 2 elements
        - key : "otp"
        - value : "****"
```

At even node it is showing me GET api :

```
2018-10-04 18:49:58 bc22dc4a8610 GET xxx/xxx/xxx
```

And at my local console i am getting this error

```
FAILURE: responseValidationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseValidationFailureReason.unacceptableStatusCode(404))
```

Why i am getting GET request in server logs ? at what step i am doing wrong ? Do i sending the `APIParameters` parameters as query parameters or body parameters?

Comment: What is your headers?

Comment: My Headers are :- ▿ 0 : 
        - key : "Content-Type"
        - value : "application/json"
      ▿ 1 : 2 elements
        - key : "Accept"
        - value : "application/json"

Comment: Can you try to remove the `validate()`? The error shows that you got 404 from `validate()`

Comment: I have done that , still the same response.

Comment: Did you try to send the same request (including same values for parameters, headers...) using Postman ? It's an alternative to check if the issue comes from your code or something else.

Comment: Yes , same request in postman gives right result but though my function it is showing wrong.